# Issues accessing localStorage with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect, local-storage

I'm trying to run a function when body loads, that will check if the user is logged in, and if not redirect them to the login page. Here is the login function :

```
function login() {
  var mail = document.getElementById('mail').value; //get values
  var psw = document.getElementById('psw').value; //get values
  localStorage.setItem('logged_in', true); //specify that user is logged in
  localStorage.setItem('mail', mail); //store mail
  window.location.replace('pages/home.html'); //redirect to home page
}
```

And the function to check if the user is logged in :

```
function check_logged_in() {
  const logged_in = localStorage.getItem('logged_in');
  if (logged_in == null) { //check if user is logged in
    alert('You are not logged in, you are about to be redirected. '); //alert user
    window.location.replace("../index.html"); //redirect to login page
  }
}
```

The problem is that even if the login function run before, I am redirected. I think that the localStorage resets on each redirection. If that is the problem, do you know the way to prevent this, or if it isn't the problem, do you know what it might be?

Comment: *"The problem is that even if the login function run before, I am redirected. I think that the localStorage resets on each redirection."* Not unless you're doing something to clear it. [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is persistent across page loads and even across sessions. It's only cleared when the browser decides it doesn't need to store that data anymore (for instance, running out of space) or you clear it (or the user does via devtools).

Comment: So what do you think the problem might be?

Comment: It's impossible to say, you'll need to debug it. Watch exactly when the local storage disappears. Make sure `login` and `check_logged_in` are running in pages on the same origin (it looks like they are given the paths above). Look for `localStorage.clear()` in your code. Etc., etc.

Comment: I highly recommend doing this on the server side!!!

Comment: Are you running your code using `file://` protocol or some kind of local server (e.x. `live-server-`). Also, aren't you using incognito mode?

Comment: I'm running my file using the `file://` protocol.

Comment: there you go, you have an issue there ... you need a server, not `file://` protocol

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try

Comment: And also @Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) a localStorage item can either be **null** (when it's empty) or a string. It does not store any other data types.

The expression

```
localStorage.setItem("logged_in", true);
```

Does not save a boolean value to the localStorage item. instead, it saves the string value `"true"`

Comment: This is true, but it's not an answer to the OP's question, since the OP is doing a `== null` check. **Any** value stored and retained will make that check false, since `getItem` never returns `undefined` and only returns `null` when there's no value for the key.

Comment: Correct. The question is suggesting that the redirect is resetting the LocalStorage item, (Which couldn't be the case) while the actual critical issue in the code sample provided is the incorrect data type provided to the setItem function.

Based on the code provided I suppose the logout function might as well be something like  `localStorage.setItem("logged_in", false);` which means the expression `logged_in == null` will always evaluate to false even after running the logout function.

Comment: I know that's not exactly what's stated in the question but it's more likely that the OP got a little confused, because otherwise, there's nothing wrong with the given code